# adjusting height in bootstrap css image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my css which handles image on my page:

**Sample [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/opdqL)**

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 10%;
    height:400px important!;
    margin-left: 33%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    height: auto;
}
```

As I increase or decrease width, it reflects well. but changing width does not make any effect.

How can I manually increase or decrease the image width here? 
css code is in index.php itself as inline css.

**I want increasing the width must not increase the height of image**

Comment: try increasing the width inside image tag ` <img width="200%">`

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle?

Comment: @user3065197: fiddle please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, **I want increasing the width must not increase the height of image** means that you want a way to change the width of an image, while keeping the height constant. If you're happy with doing this through CSS, you can wrap the image in an encapsulating div, control the div's size, and then tell the image to completely fill up the div.

The code boils down to:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .img-responsive {
           height:100%;
           width:100%;
        }

      .image-container
      {
        width:250px;
        height:140px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container image-container">
      <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-4.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
</body>
```

If you change the width or height attributes of the image-container class, you'll see that the image stretches correspondingly.

Comment: I appreciate the acceptance anyway. This is my first accepted answer! Hopefully this is what you were looking for.